# Real-world datasets for testing the maximum edge bi-clique problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, bipartite-graphs

We have proposed a new approach to solve the [maximum edge bi-clique problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003330), however,  we couldn't succeed to find real-world datasets (graph or bipartite graph datasets) to test our approach. Does anyone have an idea where I could find some datasets for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this problem has many applications in data mining, you probably should take a look at datasets used as benchmarks in papers on the topic. As an example, [this recent paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/10121476) mostly uses graphs from the [KONECT Project](http://konect.cc/).

Answer (score 3):

There are zillions of datasets online where you could run your algorithm, including:

1. [Snippet of Google web graph](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Google.html) from Stanford's SNAP.
2. [Snippet of Facebook friend graph](https://sociograph.blogspot.com/2011/03/facebook100-data-and-parser-for-it.html).
3. [Graphs from this course](https://www.ait-budapest.com/syllabuses/structure-and-dynamics-of-complex-networks) including biological, cellular, ecological, neural, and drug-target networks.
4. [Data from the SafeGraph consortium](https://www.safegraph.com/blog/safegraph-partners-with-dewey), including natural disasters and the spread of COVID.

Of course, there are many more. This is just what I had handy on my Favorites list.